# compile scss with node.js from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, sass, node-sass

I am trying to compile scss using node.js and node-sass module, the problem is that i was only able to compile sass code, when i insert scss code it says error wrong syntax. Odd is that when i put the same code to file and compile from *.scss file it works. Unfortunately nature of my application requires that it is compiled from string. Anyone has some ideas ? ;)

this is the code that works:

```
var sass = require('node-sass');

/* test.scss content: $text-color:#555555;\nbody{background:$text-color;} */

var output = sass.render({
    file: __dirname + '/test.scss',
    indentedSyntax: true,
    outputStyle : 'expanded'
}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    if(result) console.log(result, result.css.toString()); 
});
```

and this is the one that doesnt:

```
var sass = require('node-sass');

var dataTemp = '$text-color:#555555;\nbody{background:$text-color;}';

var output = sass.render({
    data: dataTemp,
    indentedSyntax: true,
    outputStyle : 'expanded'
}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    if(result) console.log(result, result.css.toString()); 
});
```

It seems odd because [official doc](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) contains example with using scss code from data.

Comment: Looks like it's somehow sensitive to spaces:
`var dataTemp = '$text-color: #555555;\nbody {background: $text-color;}';`
 - this variant works for me

Comment: this is in some way true, so basically if You use new line after opening curly brackets it will cause error, it also doesnt work with all syntax options, its like "selective" working, in this way its no good, code will be written in textarea so it makes it impossible to handle it like that. maybe someone knows how to make it unsensitive to new lines or spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#indentedsyntax), `indentedSyntax` option enables indent-sensitive [sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) mode. Looks like render expects sass and fails when gets scss instead. Try to remove this line:

```
indentedSyntax: true,
```

I guess in the first case when you loaded code from the file, renderer used .scss extension to determine syntax rules. Hope it helps.